# Use state from props with Hooks when top Component uses ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, this is my first time using Hooks and also be aware that Im learning please. Im currently working on a group project were only I was allowed to use React Hooks, we are working on a front-end project. I'll try my best to detail everything. We have an App class component were we hold default state `currentProduct: ''`. We use `componentDidMount()` to get data from an API and then update the state to be by default, the first product from an Array of Objects.

I created a separate component called `RelatedItems`, where Im using hooks.

This is how my component looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const RelatedItems = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(props.currentProduct);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(props.currentProduct);
  }, [items])

  return (
    <div className="Related-Items">
      <h1>Related Items</h1>
      <h3>{items}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RelatedItems;
```

I tried using `useEffect` looking at the Docs and some other articles in StackOverflow, but I still keep my items state as an empty string. I figured it's happening because essentially `componentDidMount` is an async function.

This is how the App component looks like:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentProduct: ''
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e, id) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ currentProduct: Number(id) })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/sedna/products')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          currentProduct: response.data[0].id
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello Sedna</h1>
        <SearchBar handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        <RelatedItems currentProduct={this.state.currentProduct} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm rendering items in an H3 just to test that I get the proper state, any feedback is welcome! Sorry any grammar mistakes

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but it doesn't look like you need any hooks or state in RelatedItems. You can just pass it in through props and then it will rerender when the state updates in the parent component.

Comment: @andrewgi Im trying to set the state of my component based on the prop that I get from the top component while using Hooks, keep in mind Im brand new to Hooks so Im not really sure of when to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will result in an infinite loop if the useEffect ever fires because the dependency is changed by the `useEffect`.

Instead you want the dependency to be the passed prop, so that when the prop changes the `useEffect` is triggered and the state is updated appropriately.

```
const RelatedItems = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(props.currentProduct);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(props.currentProduct);
  }, [props.currentProduct])

  return (
    <div className="Related-Items">
      <h1>Related Items</h1>
      <h3>{items}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Keep in mind though that setting state from props is a bit of an anti-pattern because it fragments the state so there is no longer a single source of truth. (If you change `items` in `RelatedItems` the parent will hold a different value)

For this reason you are better off handling state management in the parent and passing props to the child for rendering.

```
const RelatedItems = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="Related-Items">
      <h1>Related Items</h1>
      <h3>{props.currentProduct}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate data inside the component state, you should specify `props.currentProduct` as a hook dependency.

```
...
    useEffect(() => {
      setItems(props.currentProduct);
    }, [props.currentProduct])
...
```

**But** in the code that you have given, the `RelatedItems` component does not need an own state at all. In any case, it will be re-render when the prop changes

```
const RelatedItems = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="Related-Items">
      <h1>Related Items</h1>
      <h3>{props.currentProduct}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the help!